# ajax test not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I tried to get a simple ajax-test working but without success. I am trying to pass a variable($add1) from PHP to JS, then let the JS calculate the sum and return it back to a PHP variable via $_POST and ECHO it out in the html.

**index.php:**

```
<?php 

echo "<script type='text/javascript' src='script.js'></script>";
$add1 = 3;
echo "<script>sum($add1)</script>";
$sum = $_POST['variable'];

echo $sum;

?>
```

**script.js:**

```
function sum(param) {
    var sum = 3;
    sum = 3 + param;

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'index.php',
        data: {
            'variable': sum
        },
    });
}
```

For some reason this code doesn't work. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: So what is the problem?

Comment: Do you see any error in `console`?

Comment: You are mixing front end code with backend code

Comment: @Tushar: i am getting "ReferenceError: $ is not defined" at line 5 ("$.ajax")

Comment: Include jquery first

Comment: *$ is not defined* - jQuery reference not included.

Comment: I recommend to follow the jQuery tutorial: https://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/. The first thing it says is *"The src attribute in the <script> element must point to a copy of jQuery. Download a copy of jQuery from the Downloading jQuery page and store the jquery.js file in the same directory as your HTML file."*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want the php file to pass the $add1 to the Javascript and then i want the javascript to return the var sum back to the php and the php to echo the $sum from the $POST.

`$sum` from `$_POST` is actually echoed, but not shown in HTML page, but handled as a response back to Ajax.

You have to add a `success` function in Ajax closure

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'index.php',
        data: {
            'variable': sum
        },
        success: function (data){
            document.write(data);
        }
    });
```

You will see the answer show in page.

php:

```
if (isset($_POST['variable'])) {
    $sum = some_futher_function($_POST['variable']);
    echo $sum;
} else {
    echo "<script type='text/javascript' src='script.js'></script>";
    $add1 = 3;
    echo "<script>sum({$add1})</script>";

}
function some_futher_function($param){
    //do some thing
     return $return;
}
```

Comment: and how can i echo the answer in php ??

Comment: what's your purpose? just show in page or do further functional handle in PHP?

Comment: well i want to do further functional handle in php (some calculations in php which is no problem because the $sum is populating the value from JS) and in the end i want to echo it in the php to be visible in the html.

Comment: I know, as I told you, the answer is handled as a response back to Ajax, so you should show in page using JavaScript code in `success` function waiting some minutes  for me, I will edit my answer.

Comment: But the output is taking place in the JS.. I just want the output to take place in the PHP. With "response back to ajax" do you actually mean that PHP sends my "echo" back to ajax which is then echoed in the success fct() ??? **so if i understand you correctly: The document.write within the success fct() prints out the "response back" from the php which is acutally the PHP variable $sum??**

Answer (score 1):

Include this on your page before your `script`.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**PHP code**

```
<?php 

if ($_POST['variable']) { // If ajax request only
    $sum = $_POST['variable'] + $add1;
    echo $sum;
} else { // Loading in the browser
    $add1 = 3;
    echo '<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>';

    echo "<script>sum(".$add1.")</script>";
}
?>
```

**Javascript**

```
function sum(param) {
    var sum = 3;
    sum = 3 + param;

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'index.php',
        data: {
            'variable': sum
        },
        success: function(result) {
            alert(result)
        },
        error: function(e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: thanks, worked like a charm. Can you please explain me what you re doing in the if() ?? `if ($_POST['variable']) {
    $sum = $_POST['variable'] + $add1;
    echo $sum;`

Comment: It still doesn't work like its supposed to do. I want the php file to pass the $add1 to the Javascript and then i want the javascript to return the var sum back to the php and the php to echo the $sum from the $POST.